# Heroku - The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku, deployment

I tried deployed mern app to heroku and it deployed successfully, but when I click open the app, I get this error:

```
The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "express-react-starter",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x",
    "npm": "6.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.4.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "^2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint": "^7.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "helmet": "^4.4.1",
    "jade": "^1.11.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.12",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.1",
    "sendgrid": "^5.2.3",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.12.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./server/server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"react-scripts start\" \"nodemon server/server.js\"",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

In every file I use env varibales I use this snippet in the start of the file:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    require('dotenv').config();
}
```

Everything about deployment was successful and I didn't have any errors on both console and gui in heroku web app